# Break shapefile into small chunks, import into Google Maps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps

I have a shapefile of tax parcels that is pretty large (250MB).  I want to bring this into Google Maps, so we can see when we cross from one tax parcel into another.  This is easy to see because GPS is enabled. I figured out the workflow with a small subset of the data to convert it to a KML, load it into Google MyMaps, which then allows me to see it in Google Maps on my computer or on a mobile device. However, Google only allows users to upload data in 5MB chunks at a time.

So my question is, can anyone recommend a good workflow to divide this large shapefile into small chunks for Google Maps?  If it helps, this layer is also hosted as a map service.

Comment: import into Google Fusion Tables

Comment: I would split them in a way that is relevant to your project. For instance, if the parcels are for a county, you could try to split them up by cities. Or census districts. Or township and range areas.

Comment: I think what I am really asking is how can I automate or quickly do this process of breaking these parcels up into small chunks.  Unfortunately a 5mb chunk in this situation is too small to be meaningful, such as a town.